# @azure/storage-blob how to get result of uploadStream image url from Azuree

Tags: node.js, azure, stream, next.js

I am uploading a stream to azure blob container and it uploads to the container just fine, but I don't know how to get the url that the image created so I can return it to my initial call and render it in my UI.

I can get the request ID back, would that allow me to do a request from there and get the image URL, do I need another request and if so how would I compose that?

Thanks ahead of time

I have the following

```
import formidable from 'formidable';
let streamifier = require('streamifier');
const fs = require('fs');
const os = require('os');

const {
  BlobServiceClient,
  StorageSharedKeyCredential,
  newPipeline
} = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const containerName1 = 'images';
const ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
const uploadOptions = { bufferSize: 4 * ONE_MEGABYTE, maxBuffers: 20 };

const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(
  process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
  process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY
);
const pipeline = newPipeline(sharedKeyCredential);

const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
  `https://${process.env.AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net`,
  pipeline
);

// first we need to disable the default body parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
};

export default async function image(req, res) {
  try {
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = os.tmpdir();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
      var oldPath = files.image.path;
      var rawData = fs.readFileSync(oldPath);

      const buffer = rawData;

      const stream = streamifier.createReadStream(buffer);

      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(
        containerName1
      );
      const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(
        files.image.name
      );

      const result = await blockBlobClient.uploadStream(
        stream,
        uploadOptions.bufferSize,
        uploadOptions.maxBuffers,
        { blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'image/jpeg' } }
      );

      console.log('result >>>>', result);
      // HERE I AM TRYING TO GET THE IMAGE URL, BUT IT JUST GIVES ME A OBJECT WITH REQUEST 
      // ID AND SUCH

      res.status(200).send({ message: 'File Uploaded' });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you're interested in is getting the blob URL, you don't have to do anything special. [`BlockBlobClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest) has a property called [`url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#url) which will give you the URL of the blob.

Your code could be as simple as:

```
res.status(200).send({ message: 'File Uploaded', url: blockBlobClient.url });
```